# How to debug failures to find page titles in dokuwiki?

Tags: debug, dokuwiki

After an upgrade to `dokuwiki` 2017-02-19a "Frusterick Manners" the search function no longer finds the complete set of pages, e.g. if I search for `linux` it shows `programs:zfs_on_linux` in the search results, but not `programs:linux`. How could I debug this issue given the fact that `dokuwiki` has no logs and that the webserver (Apache 2.4) log doesn't contain any useful entries.